# duktape use common c function for multiple bound js functions

Tags: c, duktape

I'm trying to bind a common c function to multiple javascript functions using the duktape engine.

My problem is that i need to find out the name of the calling function inside the common c function. I feel like it's possible to implement this using the often referred javascript stack.

However i have no concrete idea on how to implement it. Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

Below You can find my mwe. The function **duk_get_invoking_function** is meant to be pseudo code that emphasizes my intent.

```
#include "duktape.h"

duk_ret_t common_function(duk_context * ctx) {
    const char * function_name;

    //
    // function_name = duk_get_invoking_function(ctx);
    // e.g. function_name is "func_01"
    //

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    duk_context * ctx;

    ctx = duk_create_heap_default();
    if (!ctx) {
        return 1;
    }

    duk_push_c_function(ctx, common_function, DUK_VARARGS);
    duk_put_global_string(ctx, "func_01");

    duk_push_c_function(ctx, common_function, DUK_VARARGS);
    duk_put_global_string(ctx, "func_02");

    duk_push_c_function(ctx, common_function, DUK_VARARGS);
    duk_put_global_string(ctx, "func_03");

    duk_eval_string(ctx, "func_01('abc'); func_02(123); func_03();");

    duk_destroy_heap(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want multiple Ecmascript function objects to bind to the same native function -- and when that native function is called, figure out which Ecmascript function object was used in the call.

If so, you don't need to look at the call stack to do this: each duk_push_c_function() creates a new Ecmascript function object that points to the same native function. When the native function is called, you can use duk_push_current_function() to get access to the Ecmascript function used in the call. You can then distinguish between the Ecmascript function objects based on e.g. their properties which you set when you create them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly.  I have used 
 `duk_push_c_function(...);  duk_push_string(ctx, "name"); 
 duk_push_string(ctx, "func_01");  duk_def_prop(ctx, -3, DUK_DEFPROP_HAVE_VALUE);  duk_put_global_string(ctx, "func_01");` 
 to define the functions property "name" during registration. In the handler i am accessing this property with the following code 
`duk_push_current_function(ctx);  duk_get_prop_string(ctx, -1, "name"); 
 function_name = duk_get_string(ctx, -1);`